# Remove video / Extract audio from Ogg Theora Video to Ogg Vorbis

Tags: linux, audio, ogg, vorbis, theora

I have some songs that are in .ogg format but they also contain video (which just shows the album cover the whole song, if played in a video player). How can I losslessly remove the video part of the files? The audio format is already Vorbis encoded with Lavc56.60.100 libvorbis.
Hopefully the solution doesn't include re-encoding the file with ffmpeg/avconv..

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use FFmpeg (for example, if you use it regularly and don't want to have countless single-use-applications on your computer), you can use it **without re-encoding**:

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.ogv -vn -c:a copy output_audio.ogg
```

(`-vn`: no video. `-c:a copy`: just copy the audio-stream.) [Source1](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.ogv -an -c:v copy output_audio.ogv
```

(`-an`: no audio. `-c:v copy`: just copy the video-stream.) [Source1](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Main-options)

Or, instad of `-vn` / `-an`, you can also specify the streams to copy with `-map`:

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.ogv -map 0:0 -c:a copy output_audio.ogg
```

(Only map first stream (of first input-file) to output) [Source2](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options)

Note that you can find out the stream number (and its content) via FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input_video.ogv -hide_banner
```

(`-hide_banner` is not necessary, but the output will be easier on the eye as it doesn't show you the build-infos of FFmpeg.)

Comment: +1 for adding an ffmpeg answer, can you confirm it doesnt re-encode?

Comment: Source1 states that "copy [...] indicate[s] that the stream is not to be re-encoded."
I use FFmpeg regularly with different file-formats and never saw `copy` re-encode something - I checked that via CPU- and disk-stats (~ 0% CPU-use and ~ 100% disk-use in comparison to "regular" (re-)encodings) and comparing the outputs directly (eg following http://dericed.com/2012/display-video-difference-with-ffmpegs-overlay-filter/ : `ffmpeg -y -i fileA.mov -i fileB.mov -filter_complex '[1:v]format=yuva444p,lut=c3=128,negate[video2withAlpha],[0:v][video2withAlpha]overlay[out]' -map [out] fileA-B.mov`)

Answer (score 3):

Oh, apparently there's a tool for this called oggz-rip, I believe the package name is either [liboggz](https://repology.org/metapackage/liboggz/versions) or oggz-tools depending on your distro.

To extract audio from a .ogv file you just:

```
oggz-rip -c vorbis input_video.ogv > output_audio.ogg
```

Or if you just want video and no audio:

```
oggz-rip -c theora input_video.ogv > output_video.ogv
```

(alternatively, the command could be oggzrip rather than oggz-rip, depending on your distro.)